# SQL fetch two different rows side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting back this result set from a SQL query:

```
TypeID  Address   CityID    Zip          isPreferred
----------------------------------------------------
  1     SA-09     17986     897464654         0
  2     FF-31     17987     564646656         0
```

And the SQL query is

```
SELECT 
    rAdrs.ContactTypeID, rAdrs.StreetAddress, 
    rAdrs.CityID, rAdrs.Zip,  rAdrs.isPreferred 
FROM 
    [Address] AS rAdrs  
WHERE
    rAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND rAdrs.ContactTypeID = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    mAdrs.ContactTypeID, mAdrs.StreetAddress, 
    mAdrs.CityID, mAdrs.Zip,  mAdrs.isPreferred 
FROM 
    [Address] AS mAdrs  
WHERE 
    mAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND mAdrs.ContactTypeID = 2
```

BUT the result I want in this format:

```
TypeID  Address  CityID   Zip       TypeID    Address   CityID   Zip        Preferred
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1     SA-09    17986    897464654   2       FF-31     17987    564646656  2
```

Comment: is it only for two rows or more?

Comment: Only for two will also do. That will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use CROSS APPLY

```
select a.*,b.*
from (
SELECT 
rAdrs.ContactTypeID, rAdrs.StreetAddress, rAdrs.CityID, rAdrs.Zip,  rAdrs.isPreferred 
FROM [Address] AS rAdrs  
WHERE rAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND rAdrs.ContactTypeID = 1
) a
cross apply 
(
SELECT 
mAdrs.ContactTypeID, mAdrs.StreetAddress, mAdrs.CityID, mAdrs.Zip,  mAdrs.isPreferred 
FROM [Address] AS mAdrs  
WHERE mAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND mAdrs.ContactTypeID = 2
) b
```

demo

```
declare @t1 table(id smallint,str char(2))
insert into @t1 values (1,'aa')

declare @t2 table(id smallint,str char(2))
insert into @t2 values (2,'bb')


select a.*,b.*
from 
(select * from @t1) a
cross apply
(select * from @t2) b
```

or

```
select a.*,b.*
from @t1 a
cross apply
(
select * from @t2
) b
```

Result

```
id  str id  str
1   aa  2   bb
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something. Cross apply was that.

Comment: You are the boss

Answer (score 0):

A (implicit CROSS) JOIN works here as well:

```
SELECT rAdrs.ContactTypeID, rAdrs.StreetAddress, rAdrs.CityID, rAdrs.Zip, rAdrs.isPreferred,
       mAdrs.ContactTypeID, mAdrs.StreetAddress, mAdrs.CityID, mAdrs.Zip, mAdrs.isPreferred
  FROM [Address] AS rAdrs  
  JOIN [Address] AS mAdrs on mAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND mAdrs.ContactTypeID = 2
 WHERE rAdrs.Applicantid = 5
   AND rAdrs.ContactTypeID = 1
```

Or an explicit one:

```
SELECT rAdrs.ContactTypeID, rAdrs.StreetAddress, rAdrs.CityID, rAdrs.Zip, rAdrs.isPreferred,
       mAdrs.ContactTypeID, mAdrs.StreetAddress, mAdrs.CityID, mAdrs.Zip, mAdrs.isPreferred
  FROM [Address] AS rAdrs  
 CROSS JOIN [Address] AS mAdrs
 WHERE rAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND rAdrs.ContactTypeID = 1
   AND mAdrs.Applicantid = 5 AND mAdrs.ContactTypeID = 2
```